# Return count id's value from multiple rows in one column Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm having two tables *(relation between themTest_case.id = Test_tag.test_id)* like this:

**Test_case table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test name 1 |
| 2 | Test name 2 |
| 3 | Test name 3 |
| 4 | Test name 4 |

**Test_tag table**

| test_id | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | feature:example1 |
| 1 | package:Reports |
| 1 | QA |
| 2 | feature:example1 |
| 2 | package:Reports |
| 2 | QA |
| 3 | feature:example1 |
| 3 | package:Reports |
| 3 | QA |
| 4 | feature:newexample1 |
| 4 | package:Charts |
| 4 | QA |

The database tables and structure were already defined as I'm using a oublic library to push the results.

So, I need to return in the result the *count of the id's* and the value *feature:example1*
knowing that is a test that contains the tag *package:Reports*

So, it should return something like
**Results**

| count(id) | tag |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | feature:example1 |

I already tried some different approaches without success.

How can I do that?

Comment: `select count(*), tag from Test_Tag group by tag`?

Comment: I only want the row in the return:

| 3        |    feature:example1             |

Doing like that it would return everything.

Comment: Well I couldn't figure out why you'd want to return the tag value if you already knew what it was going to be. So just add a `where` clause to filter on that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm as confused as everyone else, but this is a shot in the dark based on the various comments.  There are much easier ways to arrive at this dataset, but I'm trying to read between the lines on your comments:

```
select
  count (t.test_id), t.tag 
from
  test_case c
  join test_tag t on c.id = t.test_id
where
  t.tag like 'feature%' and
  exists (
    select null
    from test_tag t2
    where t2.test_id = t.test_id and t2.tag = 'package:Reports'
  )
group by
  t.tag
```

Comment: Awesome! That returns exactly what I need. Thank you